# How to update the whole of the column of MySql table with one numpy array (without considering iteration)

Tags: python, mysql

Is there any clever way to update one (of many) column of one MySql table with the values of a numpy array?

I tried this code but it did not work:

```
Update MyTable set ThisCol =OneNumpyArray
```

I can of course iterate over the array and update the column values one by one with the following code, I don't think that this is the elegant and the faster way:

```
for r in range(0,MyNumpy.size):
  SqlStr="UPDATE MyTable SET ThisCol=" + str(MyNumpy[r])+" WHERE id = "+id
  (...and run this consecutive sql statements)
```

But my aim is to update entire column with my numpy array with no reference to any where clause and without iteration.

There should some way to export numpy arrays (Not insert, but update) into mysql table column without iteration.

I walked through the  numpy documentation but did not see anything handy.

Thanks in advance for your interest guys.

Comment: Where does that `id` come from, and how does it correspond to `r`, or anything else? Are you trying to set each row's `ThisCol` value to match `MyNumpy[id]` where `id` is its Row ID or other key?

Comment: As a side note, you should never be concatenating up SQL strings like that. Always use parameter binding Even when you don't have the usual [safety issues](http://xkcd.com/327/), parameters make your code run faster, make it easier to read, and make it possible for you to use further optimizations or simplifications like `executemany`.

Comment: can you set up enough so that there's actually an example to work off of? You really don't give enough detail to resolve it.